# angular ag-grid

Tags: javascript, сортировка, angular2, typescript

Имеется таблица ag-grid в которую добавляются записи, как осуществить добавление новой записи в начало списка?

```
setRowData() {
    const dataSource = {
        rowCount: null, // behave as infinite scroll
        getRows: (params) => {

            let sortField = 'id';
            let sortDir = 'asc';

            if (params.sortModel && params.sortModel.length > 0) {
                sortField = params.sortModel[0].colId;
                sortDir = params.sortModel[0].sort;
            }

            let filters = [];
            if (params.filterModel && Object.keys(params.filterModel).length > 0) {
                filters = generateFilterParams(this.fullFilters, params.filterModel);
            }

            this.userService.loadAll(params.endRow - params.startRow, params.startRow, sortField, sortDir, filters).subscribe(
                (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
                    let lastRow = -1;
                    if (res.json.length < (params.endRow - params.startRow)) {
                        lastRow = params.startRow + res.json.length;
                    }
                    params.successCallback(res.json, lastRow);
                },
                (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.alertService.error(res.json)
            );
        }
    };

    this.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: Может отсортировать по дате?

Comment: пробовал, не сортируется, добавление происходит в произвольное положение, иногда в середину, иногда в конец, иногда в начало